# Exceeding buffer size for read()

Tags: c, unix, input

```
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE   64
char input[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];

int inSize = read(0, input, MAX_BUFF_SIZE);
if(inSize <= 0 || inSize > MAX_BUFF_SIZE){
     printf("An error occurred in the read.\n");
     exit(-1);
}
```

I'm writing a program that would prompt the user for input and this input has a maximum size of 64 characters. If the user inputs more than 64 characters, the program should exit.

I believe I'm using `read()` correctly but it never ever causes any errors/exceptions even if I pass in > 64 chars. What am I doing wrong here?

Is there anyway that I can check to see if the user inputs more than 64 chars with read()?

Comment: Read the documentation for `read()`, like fizzy water suggested.  `inSize > MAX_BUFF_SIZE` will *never* happen, and `inSize == 0` is not an error.

Answer (score 2):

`read()` will never read more bytes than the amount you allow it. If you tell it to read at most 64 bytes, it will read at most 64 bytes, even if there's more data available. The yet unread bytes are available for further reading (I assume the `input` is `STDIN_FILENO`, in which case they're simply left in the stdin buffer).

Comment: but read seems to return the trailing portion of the input (the part after 64 chars)? Is there anyway I can check to see if the user enters more than 64 chars?

Comment: @user1043625 You're in the **most serious need of reading the documentation of `read()`.** Instead of making assumptions ("it seems to", etc.), you can find out that it returns the number of bytes read.

Comment: Wow, just wow. Obviously you're the one making an assumption here. When I print out input, I get the trailing part of the input.

Comment: @user1043625  How are you "printing the input"?  If read fills the buffer, then `input` is often not a properly null-terminated and using `printf` to print it will produce unreliable results.  You need to show more code.  And you really need to read the documentation.